# I am trying to download compression webpack plugin with npm but its giving me error

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, phaser-framework

Hi there this is the message that APPEARS WHEN I TRY TO RUN THE COMMAND

`npm install compression-webpack-plugin`

and this is the error:

`PS D:\phaser games\game-slot-machine> npm install compression-webpack-plugin
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: phaser3-project-template@1.1.2
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^4.41.2" from the root projectnpm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.1.0" from compression-webpack-plugin@10.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   compression-webpack-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-dnpm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Cheetay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cheetay\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-31T07_37_59_109Z-debug-0npm install compression-webpack-plugin --save-devine>
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: phaser3-project-template@1.1.2
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^4.41.2" from the root projectnpm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.1.0" from compression-webpack-plugin@10.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev compression-webpack-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
n) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Cheetay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cheetay\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-31T07_39_13_026Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\phaser games\game-slot-machine> npm install compression-webpack-plugin --save-dev
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: phaser3-project-template@1.1.2
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^4.41.2" from the root projectnpm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.1.0" from compression-webpack-plugin@10.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev compression-webpack-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Cheetay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cheetay\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-31T07_39_20_653Z-debug-0.log`

i am trying to reduce size of my js file in a game and trying to download this plugin that reduces the size.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to fix the conflict between both the dependency if you want to run both commands at one time, or using --force is also an option if you really want to compress the file.

Comment: thanks Anshul Sharma. it was installed but now when i am trying to configure my webpack with this plugin it is again giving some errors. Can you look into it.

Comment: compilation.hooks.processAssets.tapPromise({
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tapPromise')
    at D:\phaser games\game-slot-machine\node_modules\compression-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:414:39
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\phaser games\game-slot-machine\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\phaser games\game-slot-machine\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compiler.ne

Comment: the error suggests that webpack is unable to identify the type of "tapPromise". it expects both the tapPromise in node modules and where you have used in index.js to be of the same type.